# Was my SEO firm trying to sabotage my website?

Tags: php, regex, magento, seo, canonical-link

I found this code in my head.phtml after my SEO firm did a 1 time audit on my site. Were they removing canonicals from paginated content hoping It would hurt my rankings so I'd get a monthly package with them???

```
$cssjshtml=$this->getCssJsHtml();

if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']>1)
{

    $strtofind='/<link[^>]rel="canonical" href=".*"[^>]*>/i';

    //preg_replace('/(<div.*?class="name"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', '$1$3', $string);
    $html=preg_replace($strtofind, '', $cssjshtml);

    //echo '<pre>';$strtofind
        //print_r($strtofind);
    ///echo '</pre>';   
    //$cssjshtml=;

    echo $html;
}
else
{
    echo $this->getCssJsHtml();
}
```

Could there be any legitimate reason for doing this?

Original head only contains the `echo $this->getCssJsHtml();` part

Comment: Unfortunately without understanding the pieces of the puzzle, it's impossible to say. Canonicals, however, may have been hurting your rankings in this case. I suggest you contact the SEO firm and confront them.

Comment: What would have been the canonical URL for such a paginated page?

Comment: @unor It's an ecommerce site with a catalog of products. The default is the first page, without any parameters.

Comment: @remus I will need to have a chat with them after just discovering they also disavowed well written articles about our business on sites with 76+ DA

Comment: The best SEO you are going to find is an old style COPYWRITER who understands the new tech, your product and provides useful content. Third party SEO usually has no interest beyond the buck and a bunch of cargo cult SEO. I like the cold calls that start "we were looking at your site" and quickly with a few questions you ascertain they've never even looked, and they ran your homepage through one of those online SEO tools like woorank and claim to know it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1 : That may be a mistake** done by the SEO firm: `rel=canonical` to the first page of a paginated series

Imagine that you have an article that spans several pages:

```
example.com/article?story=cupcake-news&page=1
example.com/article?story=cupcake-news&page=2
and so on
```

Specifying a `rel=canonical` from page 2 (or any later page) to `page 1` is not correct use of `rel=canonical`, as these are not duplicate pages. Using `rel=canonical` in this instance would result in the content on `pages 2` and beyond not being indexed at all. [Source](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html)

**Case 2 : That may not be a mistake**
considering the recent developments. When we talk about putting paginated content accross. We do it using

```
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article-part2.html">
```

on the first page and then using

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article-part1.html">
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article-part3.html">
```

on the subsequesnt pages. Check your code for a presence of this kind of stuff. [Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en)

In case you are seeing the **first case** then be prompt and get your source code changed right away.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added the rel="next" and rel="prev" in addition to restoring the original canonical. Hopefully our 600+ pages of duplicate content will disappear from webmaster tools soon!